Future Drupal 7 Updates?
Apologies if this is the wrong place to ask. Has there been any statement on how long CiviCRM is likely to continue releasing Drupal 7 builds of new updates? I've seen the Compuco Never Ending Support offer, but just wondering if there's an offical position from CiviCRM itself? Trying once again to put together some options for our trustees in the hope of motivating some action...

At https://www.compuco.io/civicrm-drupal-7-never-ending-support it says "The CiviCRM team will also keep a maintained version of CiviCRM compatible with these updates, to keep compatibility from both sides."
And I also do remember from the compucorp webmeeting Josh from core suggested there will be continued support of the integration with drupal 7. Around 18:30 in the video at https://civicrm.org/blog/jamienovick/recordings-community-briefing-future-drupal-7

Thanks, yeah. I'm more wondering about the standard monthly releases outside of that programme. If we continue to leave Drupal 7 running outside of support, will there CiviCRM's regular updates continue to receive Drupal 7 versions for the time being, or will those cease in January?

My takeaway is that the regular monthly releases of civi will continue to work with drupal 7. Up to a point, it's community-driven, so if something is broken with drupal 7, anyone can submit a patch to fix it, and if there's positive review on it, it will likely get merged.
